# Extjs combo box within extjs form element not grayed out on disabled

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, sencha-touch, store

I am looking to gray out the entire combo box when disabled. Using the "disabled" property disables the combo box but is there any option to gray out the entire combo box when disabled? Currently it is not grayed out, is the extjs form element overriding the disabled property in some way?

The code for my combo box is as shown below.

```
Ext.define('something....', {
    controller: 'some Controller',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me,
        me = this;

        me.items = [{
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combo',
                itemId: 'nameId',
                name:'nameId',
                labelAlign: 'top',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                store: me._getNames(),
                valueField:'dataId',
                displayField: 'name.firstName',
                editable: false,
                disabled: someCondition?true:false
            }]
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

disabled: true works as you want. You can check it here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cb0

Could you please review it?

Comment: it only gets disabled for me but not grayed out with the disabled option just set to true

Comment: Could you check the fiddle? Please, let me know the ExtJs version, if you use Modern or Classic framework and the theme you are using.

Comment: I am using version 4.2. I am new to extjs, can you please help mw with how do I find out the theme I am using and whether it is modern/classic?

Comment: Change that disabled: someCondition?true:false to disabled: true, perhaps you have the problem there.

Comment: @ César Zea Gómez I tried that disabled to just true but even then, I only see it being disabled but not grayed out. Do you have any ideas on where might be the issue?